# Useless use of private array in void context when getting array length

Tags: perl, while-loop

I'm trying to make a loop that stops when the length of `@arr1` and `@arr2` are both zero. I get this warning message

```
Useless use of private array in void context
```

when I use this

```perl
while (scalar (@arr1, @arr2) ) {
  #more code
}
```

Why do I get a warning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`scalar` takes one argument. You have to use a bit more complicated

```
while (scalar @arr1 or scalar @arr2)
```

which is fortunately equivalent to shorter

```
while (@arr1 or @arr2)
```

Comment: *"stops when the length of `@arr1` and `@arr2` are both zero"* means `@arr1 or @arr2`